# How critical is it if SYSAUX is full?

Tags: oracle

I recently got an Ora-1688 alert and realized my SYSAUX is 99.7% full.
Is this a critical issue that has to be dealt with immediately?
Will this cause my system to stop?

Comment: I would check out https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33645/sysaux-tablespace-is-98 for some more info

Comment: Thanks Joe for the comment! I kinda understand how to deal with it now from reading different posts etc. However would you happen to know if this issue has to be dealt with asap or could it wait(until tmrw etc).

Comment: I am not sure what would happen if it fills up so can't say for sure but guessing it won't be good

Comment: just extend the tablespace with a new datafile

Answer (score 2):

If your Database has enabled AUDIT and your auditing tablespace SYSAUX gets 100% full,  NONE of database users will be able to log in to database anymore. Your database will not crash but only SYS db user will be able to log in - the first thing you should do in this case is to extend the SYSAUX tablespace (add a data file) and deal later with how SYSAUX got full at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link to know more about SYSTEM and SYSAUX tablespaces

[Lack of space in SYSTEM and SYSAUX tablespace in oracle 11g R2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181570/lack-of-space-in-system-and-sysaux-tablespace-in-oracle-11g-r2)

Thanks